# realloc failed - free pointer? просит cppcheck

Tags: c, realloc

Тут ситуационно проверял код `cppcheck`ом, и он ввел меня в задумчивость..

пример того кода, лишнее выпилил:

```
void * t(void * p, size_t osz)
{
    if (!(p = realloc(p, ((osz + 1) * sizeof(int)))))
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    return *p;
}
```

чего он собственно советует:

> (error) Common realloc mistake: 'p' nulled but not freed upon failure

так вопрос, как можно удалить если вернулся `NULL` ?!
или заранее скопировать адрес переменной в другую, и в случае неудачи удалять ссылку на оригинал? .. но мне почему то кажется что там тоже будет `NULL`..

проверить на практике возможности кажется нет, realloc вроде не ломается..

ваше мнение?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *или заранее скопировать адрес переменной в другую, и в случае неудачи удалять ссылку на оригинал*

Именно. Так и нужно. Только как по мне - лучше присвоить результат `realloc` другой переменной - так логичнее, типа

```
void * newPtr = realloc(p,....
if (newPtr == NULL) 
{ 
    ... обработка проблем; p содержит указатель на старый блок
} 
else
{
    p = newPtr;
}
```

> *но мне почему то кажется что там тоже будет NULL*

Ну если вы делаете

```
int x = 5;
int *i = &x;
int *j = i;
i = NULL;
```

то не боитесь, что в `j` тоже будет `NULL`? :)

И последнее: а как вы ухитряетесь возвращать разыменованный указатель на `void` в качестве `void*`? :)

Comment: Спасибо, это сильно кастрированный вариант :) с `void`ами :) а в примере с `i`,`j` это не указатели друг на друга.. :) а NULL возможно сообразит сам `realloc` внутри себя на передоваемый ему параметр.. в этом я конечно неуверен, и наверняка зависит от реализации.

Comment: В С передача параметров в функцию выполняется только по значению (когда говорят об отдельной передаче по адресу - это просто передача адреса по значению :)) - поэтому изменить передаваемую переменную `realloc` никак не может. Почитайте еще раз о передаче аргументов в функции. А в примере, от того, что вы замените на указатели... Вобщем, я исправляю в ответе на указатели - смотрите сами.

Comment: Да, да, с нулем (NULL) согласен конечно :) а так `i = ((int*)&0);` ?

Comment: И как вы планируете найти адрес нуля? :) Но даже так - в моем примере *НИКАКОЕ ИЗМЕНЕНИЕ ЗНАЧЕНИЯ `i` НЕ ПОВЛИЯЕТ НА ИЗМЕНЕНИЕ ЗНАЧЕНИЯ `j`*

Comment: Вполне согласен :)